# Detect needed print orientation with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to create xls spreadsheets. Is there a way to detect if the data fits in portrait mode or if I have to set the sheet to landscape mode? I know how to set the modes, but I don't know how to find out if the data fits the current print orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried but cant see a way to get this working.

When you create the workbook, poi defaults the Fit Height and Width to 1 each.

> Fit Height is the number of pages high
>   to fit sheet in

and

> Fit Width is the number of pages wide
>   to fit sheet in

Unless you set the sheet print height and width to a higher value like so,

```
sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)10);

System.out.println (sheet.getPrintSetup().getFitWidth());
System.out.println (sheet.getPrintSetup().getFitHeight());
```

always return 1 and 1

The problem is Excel will always compress the data (in zoom size) down to 10% to fit the 1 x 1 page layout. [In MS_Excel, this shows up as `Print Preview > Page Setup > Scaling > Down to X% of actual size`  ]

Once the zoom is at 10%, it then overflows the data onto page 2 and so on.

I've tried a sheet with lots of data and even sent a large PrintArea

```
workBook.setPrintArea(
                    0, //sheet index
                    0, //start column
                    50, //end column
                    0, //start row
                    520  //end row
            );
```

on a variety of print sizes.

```
sheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize((short)11); // A5
```

So the default printable area / orientation are not changed unless you override them, so I dont think the data can be detected to be larger than the printable area - which is what you're trying to obtain.

This might be one for the POI mailing lists.

**Updated** to include link to this discussion on POI mailing lists as already asked by OP.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201010.mbox/%3c4CBDD258.80407@openforce.com%3e

Comment: I already asked this question on the POI mailing list and didn't get an answer. Oh well..maybe the answer is that it's not possible - like you mentioned. I'll wait another couple days and see if someone comes up with a solution (I doubt it though)

Answer (score 6):

```
   HSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short) 1);
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short) 0);
    sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
    printSetup .setLandscape(true);

   HSSFFooter footer = wygSheet.getFooter();
    footer.setCenter("Page " + HSSFFooter.page() + " of "+ HSSFFooter.numPages());
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, but if I change the setFitHeight to 1 from 0, then it worked